# Optimal way of counting the number of non-overlapping pairs given a list of intervals

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, performance, optimization

I'm trying to count the number of non-overlapping pairs given a list of intervals.

For example:

```
[(1, 8), (7, 9), (3, 10), (7, 12), (11, 13), (13, 14), (9, 15)]
```

There are 8 pairs:

```
((1, 8), (11, 13))
((1, 8), (13, 14))
((1, 8), (9, 15))
((7, 9), (11, 13))
((7, 9), (13, 14))
((3, 10), (11, 13))
((3, 10), (13, 14))
((7, 12), (13, 14))
```

I can't seem to figure out a better solution other than to just brute force it by comparing everything with virtually everything else, resulting in a O(n^2) solution.

```
def count_non_overlapping_pairs(intervals):
    intervals = list(set(intervals))  # deduplicate any intervals
    intervals.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    pairs = 0
    for i in range(len(intervals)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(intervals)):
            if intervals[i][1] < intervals[j][0]:
                pairs += 1
    return pairs
```

Is there a more optimal solution than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the intervals, once by start point, once by end point.

Now, given an interval, perform a binary search using the start point in the intervals sorted by end point. The index you get tells you how many non-overlapping intervals come before: All intervals that end before your interval starts are non-overlapping.

Do the same for the end point: Do a binary search in the array of intervals sorted by start point. All intervals that start after your interval ends are non-overlapping.

All other intervals either start before your interval ends, but after it has started, or end after your interval starts, but start before it.

Do this for every interval, sum the results. Make sure to halve, to not count intervals twice. This looks as follows:

Overall you get O(n log n): Two sorts, O(n) times two O(log n) binary searches.

Now observe that half of this is not even needed - if A and B are two non-overlapping intervals, it suffices if B counts the intervals before it, including A; A doesn't need to count the intervals after it. This lets us simplify the solution further; you just need to sort the end points to be able to count the intervals before an interval, and of course we now don't need to halve the resulting sum anymore:

```py
# Counting the intervals before suffices
def count_non_overlapping_pairs(intervals):
    ends = sorted(interval[1] for interval in intervals)
    def count_before(interval):
        return bisect_left(ends, interval[0])
    return sum(map(count_before, intervals))
```

(Symmetrically, you could also just count the intervals after an interval.)

Comment: I don't understand why you even mention the first method. What's the point? I suggest that you ditch that and just count the intervals before (or after) each interval? Perhaps you initially counted both ends and then realized there's a better way, but that's no reason to keep the inferior solution as part of your answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Indeed I realized this. I still think there's value in documenting how I arrived at this solution, rather than just presenting the finished solution - similarly to writing down an equation, only to show that a lot of it cancels out in the end. I have removed the code for the "inferior solution" though because that obstructed the answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list and do a binary search (using `bisect` module):

```py
from bisect import bisect

lst = [(1, 8), (7, 9), (3, 10), (7, 12), (11, 13), (13, 14), (9, 15)]
lst.sort()

out = []
for a, b in lst:
    for t in lst[bisect(lst, (b, float("inf"))) :]:
        out.append(((a, b), t))
print(*out, sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```py
((1, 8), (9, 15))
((1, 8), (11, 13))
((1, 8), (13, 14))
((3, 10), (11, 13))
((3, 10), (13, 14))
((7, 9), (11, 13))
((7, 9), (13, 14))
((7, 12), (13, 14))
```

---

EDIT: If you want only count:

```py
lst = [(1, 8), (7, 9), (3, 10), (7, 12), (11, 13), (13, 14), (9, 15)]
lst.sort()

cnt = sum(len(lst) - bisect(lst, (b, float("inf"))) for a, b in lst)
print(cnt)
```

Prints:

```
8
```

Comment: Note that this is still O(n²) in the worst case that there are O(n²) many non-overlapping pairs (all intervals are pairwise disjoint). You'd have to only count to achieve better time complexity.

Comment: @Luatic I've added version that just counts.

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed this up I can think of would be to just stop the inner loop and add plus one for all remaining elements whenever the condition is fulfilled, while ensuring the list is sorted by second value and then first value of each tuple pair:

```
def count_non_overlapping_pairs(intervals):
    intervals = sorted(set(intervals), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
    pairs = 0
    for i in range(len(intervals)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(intervals)):
            if intervals[i][1] < intervals[j][0]:
                pairs += len(intervals) - j
                break
    return pairs
```

Although I would guess @Luatics solution using binary search is probably faster for large lists.